# TypeError only with celery

Tags: django, celery, typeerror

I am using Django. So there is an option `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER`.
When I switch off celery workers with `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True`, everything is ok.

When `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False` I get an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'unicode'
```

That's an error when I try to deduct one timestamp from another. Smth like:
`new_date - old_date`

What's wrong with celery? How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't realize why is it happening, smth in celery engine.

Here is how to cope with it.
I calculated these timestamps in one task and then passed them as arguments to another celery tasks.
So, when `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True` they passed as normal `datestamp`. When `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False`, they passed as `unicode`.

Following check resolved the problem:

```
if isinstance(newest_date, unicode):
    old_date = pytz.utc.localize(
        datetime.datetime.strptime(old_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%fZ'))
    new_date = pytz.utc.localize(
        datetime.datetime.strptime(new_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%fZ'))
```